# Code running on UNO doesn't run on MEGA

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

the code posted below runs perfectly on UNO, but the loop only runs for twice or thrice (figured this out by printing out "TEST" on the Serial Monitor) on the Arduino mega. Someone can tell me what's wrong with this? It's a 4wd robot which runs on RF Joystick. The circuit has a RF receiver connected to digital pin 2. Also, I noticed that when all the functions are removed from the loop, it runs perfectly. 
However, as my suspicion that the board is not functioning properly, I tried uploading other programs to the MEGA and they run flawlessly.Including the "ESP8266 as a shield controlled using the Blynk app version" of this code.

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>
int RF_RX_PIN = 2;// RF signal from joystick
void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;  
AF_DCMotor rb(4);//means rightside,back wheel
AF_DCMotor lb(3);//leftside, back wheel
AF_DCMotor rf(1);
AF_DCMotor lf(2);
  int xh,xl,yh,yl;
  uint8_t z;
  uint8_t button;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_set_rx_pin(RF_RX_PIN);  // Setup receive pin.
  vw_setup(2000); // Transmission speed in bits per second.
  vw_rx_start(); // Start the PLL receiver.
  pinMode(servopin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  rf.run(RELEASE);
  lf.run(RELEASE);
  lb.run(RELEASE);
  rb.run(RELEASE);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
}

uint8_t buffer[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN]; // buffer array for data recieve over serial port 
uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
int x=0;
int y=0;
int state=2;

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("TEST");
  if(vw_get_message(buffer, &buflen)) // non-blocking I/O
  {
    decode();
  if ((x==0 && y==0) || z==1){rstop();}
  else {
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(y);
  godirection(x,y);
  }
  }else{
    state=2;
    rstop();
  }
}

void decode()
{
  if((buffer[0]!=0x7E)||(buffer[4]!=0xEF))
  {
  resetFunc();
  } 
  uint8_t i = 0;
  x = buffer[1]<<2;
  y = buffer[2]<<2;
  z = buffer[3]>>3;
  button = buffer[3]&0x07;
   if (x>600){
    x=1;
  }else if (x<=600 && x>=400){x=0;}
  else {x=-1;}
  if (y>600){
    y=1;
  }else if (y<=600 && y>=400){y=0;}
  else {y=-1;}
}

void clearBufferArray()              // function to clear buffer array
{
  for (int i=0; i<VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;i++)
    { buffer[i]=0;}                  // clear all index of array with command NULL
}
void godirection(int x,int y) {
     if (x==0){
      if (y==1){forward();}
      else if (y==0){rstop();}
      else if (y==-1){backward();}
     }
     else if (x==1){
      if (y==1){srf();}
      else if (y==0){right();}
      else if (y==-1){srb();}
     }
     else if (x==-1){
      if(y==1){slf();}
      else if (y==0){left();}
      else if (y==-1){slb();}
     }
}

void rstop (){
  if (state==0){
  rf.run(FORWARD);lf.run(FORWARD);lb.run(FORWARD);rb.run(FORWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
  delay(75);
  rf.run(RELEASE);lf.run(RELEASE);lb.run(RELEASE);rb.run(RELEASE);
  rf.setSpeed(0);lf.setSpeed(0);rb.setSpeed(0);lb.setSpeed(0);
  state=2;
}
else if (state==1){
  rf.run(BACKWARD);lf.run(BACKWARD);lb.run(BACKWARD);rb.run(BACKWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
  delay(75);
  rf.run(RELEASE);lf.run(RELEASE);lb.run(RELEASE);rb.run(RELEASE);
  rf.setSpeed(0);lf.setSpeed(0);rb.setSpeed(0);lb.setSpeed(0);
  state=2;
}
else if (state==2){
    rf.run(RELEASE);lf.run(RELEASE);lb.run(RELEASE);rb.run(RELEASE);
  rf.setSpeed(0);lf.setSpeed(0);rb.setSpeed(0);lb.setSpeed(0);
}
}

void forward(){
  state=1;
  rf.run(FORWARD);lf.run(FORWARD);lb.run(FORWARD);rb.run(FORWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
}

void backward(){
  state=0;
  rf.run(BACKWARD);lf.run(BACKWARD);lb.run(BACKWARD);rb.run(BACKWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
}

void right(){
  state=2;
  rf.run(BACKWARD);lf.run(FORWARD);lb.run(FORWARD);rb.run(BACKWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
}
void left(){
  state=2;
  lf.run(BACKWARD);rf.run(FORWARD);rb.run(FORWARD);lb.run(BACKWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(200);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(200);
}

void srf(){//srf means slanted right forward
  state=1;
  rf.run(FORWARD);lf.run(FORWARD);lb.run(FORWARD);rb.run(FORWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(50);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(50);lb.setSpeed(200);
}

void srb(){
  state=0;
  Serial.println("SRB");
  rf.run(BACKWARD);lf.run(BACKWARD);lb.run(BACKWARD);rb.run(BACKWARD);
  rf.setSpeed(50);lf.setSpeed(200);rb.setSpeed(50);lb.setSpeed(200);
}

void slf(){
  state=1;
  rf.run(FORWARD);lf.run(FORWARD);lb.run(FORWARD);rb.run(FORWARD);
  lf.setSpeed(50);rf.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(50);rb.setSpeed(200);
}

void slb(){
  state=0;
  rf.run(BACKWARD);lf.run(BACKWARD);lb.run(BACKWARD);rb.run(BACKWARD);
  lf.setSpeed(50);rf.setSpeed(200);lb.setSpeed(50);rb.setSpeed(200);
}
```

Comment: where in the program does it stop?

Comment: the whole thing stops just I couldn't find a specific place it did. the serial monitor just stops after printing two or three "TEST" s. I think the loop iteration stops. However, if all the functions such as rstop, and decode are removed, it runs again. but it is not specific to any function.

Comment: then figure out where is stops exactly

Comment: it just stops when it meets a function :(… I figured it.. any function... when it meets one.. it freezes. but any other code with any function works perfectly fine. only in this code

Comment: You need to put in a lot more print statements to figure out exactly where the program is halting.  Put a print statement at the beginning and end of each function. then you'll see which function is causing the crash.

Comment: You also need to fix your indentation. The way your rstop() function is indented, it looks like the first closing brace ends the function and the `else if (state==1)` code is outside any function. The body of the first `if` statement should be indented, and the closing brace that ends the if statement should be on the same line as the `if statement`. There are quite a few bad uses of indentation that make your code very hard to read.

Comment: There is a `servopin` variable you configure as OUTPUT. Where does it come from? From the header files? If it is not declared anywhere, i don't believe that code compiles. Or did you delete some code, and this is not all you have done?

Comment: Im sorry please ignore the servopin,,, I removed the variable declaration to make it easier to focus on this problem for you guys... forgot to delete that line